# Multiprocessing only utilizing a single core

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to create a FBM texture using the module `perlin-noise`, but it takes a very long time to execute. I've implemented `multiprocessing`, only to find that the program was still running off a single core. I've tried looking for other people with the same problem, but most threads were 7+ years old and / or involved problems and solutions related to different OSs.

My OS is Windows 8.1, I have a quad-core CPU, and I'm running Python 3.9.2

Here is the program:

```
from perlin_noise import PerlinNoise
from multiprocessing import Pool

def world(n):
    noise1 = PerlinNoise(octaves=3, seed=1)
    noise2 = PerlinNoise(octaves=6, seed=1)
    noise3 = PerlinNoise(octaves=12, seed=1)
    noise4 = PerlinNoise(octaves=24, seed=1)
    noise5 = PerlinNoise(octaves=48, seed=1)
        
    world = []
    for i in range(n):
        row = []
        for j in range(n):
            noise_val =  noise1([i/n, j/n])
            noise_val += 0.5 * noise2([i/n, j/n])
            noise_val += 0.25 * noise3([i/n, j/n])
            noise_val += 0.125 * noise4([i/n, j/n])
            noise_val += 0.0625 * noise5([i/n, j/n])
            row.append(noise_val)
        world.append(row)
    
def main():
    start = time.time()
    nums = [128]
    p = Pool()
    p.map(world, nums)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    from distributed import Client
    client = Client()
    main()
```

So, what's going on? Have I made a mistake in thinking that multiprocessing could work on these for-loops?

Thanks!

Comment: The effect won't be visible if there's only one element in ```nums```.; Plus that func look slike a o(n**2) algo, so try to make that faster or reduce that TC.

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming. Could you please tell me what an o(n**2) algorithm is, or send me some links to websites that may help me optimize my code?

Comment: O(n**2) is the time complexity of an algorithm. I would suggest

Comment: O(n**2) means if your data has n values, the algorithm will take about n^2 iterations. E.g. for n 1000, your algorithm will do (about) n^2 =1000000 iterations - i.e. it will get a lot slower as n increases. The reason your algorith is O(n^2) is that you have one for loop nested inside another. Each for loop does n interations so overall you have n*n, i.e. n^2 iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why it only use one Process is simple. You only passed 1-length list in `Pool.map`.

What `Pool(n).map(function, iterable)` does is, *applying* provided funtion to *each* element of provided `iterable`(in this case, `list`) with `n` number of worker processes.

Since you only have 128 in `nums` it's only creating one task thus no other processes are ever used.

Proper usage would look like this:

```py
from multiprocessing import pool


def work(val):
    return hash(val ** 10000000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = pool.Pool(8)

    with p:
        output = p.map(work, [i for i in range(1, 31)])

    print(output)
```

This example will have 8 processes, so utilizing 8 logical cores. Since we gave it numbers from 1 to 30, `p.map` will apply function `work` to each of those numbers using 8 processes, so it can run up to 8 functions simultaneously.

When we run it, we can see it's effect.

[image]

Of course it's using more processes to communicates between process, etc - I admit that I don't know underlying details on it.

---

Side note, to make your work more efficient, you should refrain yourself from appending as much as possible.

Check this simple example appending a lot of time and measuring time it took.

```py
>>> import timeit
>>> def appending():
...     output = []
...     for i in range(1000000):
...         output.append(i)
...     return output
... 
>>> def list_comp():
...     return [i for i in range(1000000)]

>>> print(f"{timeit.timeit(appending, number=100):.2}")
8.1

>>> print(f"{timeit.timeit(list_comp, number=100):.2}")
5.2
```

As you can see appending is pretty much more slower than [List comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) - but this doesn't mean not to use `list.append` - just don't use it excessively.

Comment: I've changed to list comprehension, but the program hasn't changed in speed at all.

Comment: Check upper part of demo. Did you changed `[128]` to something else?